# meaning: 'this made abuse of Mr X both a duty and a pleasure'

Tags: meaning-in-context, vocabulary

> The Ghost's identity had leaked swiftly into the wider community, and **this**, coupled with the knowledge that he had been jointly responsible for the drowning of a three- year-old child, **made abuse of {Mr X} both a duty and a pleasure**. 
>   (The Casual Vacancy, by J. K. Rowling)

```
'this made abuse of {Mr X} both a duty and a pleasure'
```

What does the sentence above mean? Would you parse it?

Comment: I really, really hope that paragraph isn't a vital pilot spoiler.

Comment: Potential spoiler duly pruned.

Comment: Yet I can't unread it :( Haven't read the book yet, it's in my queue...

Comment: You have sacrificed nobly for mankind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The Ghost's identity had leaked swiftly into the wider community, and
>   **this**, coupled with the knowledge that he had been jointly responsible for the drowning of a three- year-old child, **made
>   abuse** of {Mr X} both a duty and a pleasure. (The Casual Vacancy, by
>   J. K. Rowling)

The antecedent of *this* can be the *idea* expressed by a preceding clause, here, "The Ghosts's identity had ....community".

**This...coupled with the knowledge that....made abuse ... a duty and a pleasure**

That the Ghost's identity had swiftly become widely known, together with the knowledge that the ghost had caused a child's death, made it necessary to abuse him -- an obligation that the abuser was happy to meet.

In the sentences I edited out, there was a phrase, "rattling stream". The sentence you're asking about is itself a rattling stream: many words thrown together and aimed in the general direction of an idea.

Answer (score 4):

The phrase "both a duty and a pleasure" is almost an established catch-phrase.

> As a child, she [[Nightingale](http://www.manfen5.com/GZ_YY-SYS201209101018253755950759.html)] felt that visiting sick people was **both a duty and a pleasure**.

**It is a duty**... means you *should* do it, because it's the right thing to do.

**It is a pleasure**... indicates that it's something you *enjoy* doing.

(So, Nightingale didn't visit sick people only because she felt they needed the company; she actually looked forward to a chance to visit them.)

Sometimes we do something out of duty, because we feel an obligation to do so. Sometimes we do something out of pleasure, because we get quite a bit of satisfaction out of doing it. When we feel both emotions at the same time, we can use this phrase to describe our feelings:

> *Upvoting good questions on ELL is both a duty and a pleasure*.

In Rowling's novel, people felt this way about abusing Stuart – they felt he *deserved* their scorn (therefore, it was their *duty*), and they reached the point where they had grown to *enjoy* heaping it upon him (therefore, it was their *pleasure*).